# Why does the Mithril child component state change not trigger an update?

Tags: mithril.js

The following code works as expected: it creates two counter buttons that persist their state and update on clicking:

```js
let Counter = function (vnode) {
  let count = 0

  return {
    view: (vnode) => {
      return m("button",
        {
          onclick: function () {
            console.log(count++)
          }
        }, "Count: " + count)
    }
  }
}

let Counters = {
  view: () => [
    m(Counter),
    m(Counter),
  ]
}

m.mount(document.body, Counters)
```

However, if I define the array of `Counter` components in a separate variable and pass that to the `Counters` view function, then the view stops updating. The state persists and I can see incrementing count logged to console, but nothing changes on screen. This is the updated code:

```js
let Counter = function (vnode) {
  let count = 0

  return {
    view: (vnode) => {
      return m("button",
        {
          onclick: function () {
            console.log(count++)
          }
        }, "Count: " + count)
    }
  }
}

let counters = 
  [
    m(Counter),
    m(Counter),
  ]
let Counters = {
  view: () => counters
}

m.mount(document.body, Counters)
```

Why would this be happening? This is a toy example of a more complicated Mithril application that I'm working on, where I would like to arbitrarily sort the array of child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to gather useful feedback in the Mithril Gitter chat and will post what I learned below.

The reason the counters in my example were not updating was because they were defined once inside the `counters` array and it was returned subsequently. As the same array is returned every time the `view()` function of `Counters` is called, `Counters` does not see a need to update as it thinks that the elements it is returning have not changed. Even though the `Counter` elements inside the array update, the reference to the array remains the same.

One way of handling this is by defining a factory function that would return a new sorted array of `Counter` elements each time the `view()` function on `Counters` is called. Furthermore, the application state then needs to be kept in a global location and the only parameter passed to each `Counter` is the index of the global counter it is referencing, like so:

```js
let counterData = [0, 0]

let Counter = {
  view: ({
    attrs: {
      index
    }
  }) => {
    return m("button", {
      onclick: () => counterData[index]++
    }, "Count: " + counterData[index])
  }
}

let Counters = function () {
  const counters = () => {
    return counterData.sort((a, b) => a - b).map((count, i) => m(Counter, {
      index: i
    }, count))
  }

  return {
    view: () => counters()
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, Counters)
```

A working JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqmjvLew/).

Answer (score 0):

I think what may be happening is that the components are being "rendered" when you set up the array, because of how JavaScript evaluates expressions, the Mithril components in the `counters` array are already executed before you try to mount them later on, so the Mithril redraw mechanism (via `m.mount` or `m.route`) might not "know" about these components and are therefore not part of the redraw queue.

```js
let counters = 
  [
    m(Counter),
    m(Counter),
  ]
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps a better solution would be to hold the array of data in a pure JS data structure and when you need to actually render the components, you can map over the data structure, e.g.

```js
let Counter = function (vnode) {
  return {
    view: (vnode) => {
      return m("button",
        {
          onclick: function () {
            console.log(this, vnode.attrs.count++);
          }
        }, "Counter #" + vnode.attrs.id +": " + vnode.attrs.count)
    }
  }
}

let counterList = [
  { id: 1, name: "Something 1", count: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "Something 2", count: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: "Something 3", count: 0 },
]

let reorderCountersByCountAscending = () => {
  counterList.sort((a, b) => (a.count > b.count) ? 1 : -1)
}

let Counters = {
  view: () => {
    return m('div',
      m('button', { onclick: reorderCountersByCountAscending }, 'Reorder Children'),
      counterList
        .map((counterListItem) => m(Counter, counterListItem))
    )
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, Counters);
```

This isn't an ideal implementation, there's a lot of state mutation happening in very implicit ways and it can lead to much confusion in a real world application, but I hope it describes the approach.

Here are a few more examples to look at:
https://jsfiddle.net/9hu2yd1s/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @barryels. I managed to get feedback from the Mithril Gitter chat and posted the solution below. Your answer also addresses the problem in a similar manner, although it appears that additional levels of indirection slow the implementation down (that's the impression I get from the fiddle).

Comment: @phi_land_trophyist, I'm happy you got a solution from the Mithril Gitter community. With regard to the "slowness" you're seeing in the example fiddle, that's purely down to how jsfiddle is "running" the code in the preview pane. Put that example code in a plain HTML file and run it directly, you'll notice that the performance is what you would expect from Mithril... super-fast.